# MOSS Workflows: Which WorkflowInstanceId field should I be using?

Tags: 2007, workflow

Which workflow intance Id field should I use?

I have two kind of workflows in my project (associated with document in doclib and associated with basic list item in task list.

I have been told that "ows_WorkflowInstanceID" is only for documentlibrary workflows...
Still I am getting same IDs from both of those field despite which workflow task I get that value from.

And I try to get those ID from workflow task itself...

```
Guid tempIdOWS = new Guid(item["ows_WorkflowInstanceID"].ToString());

Guid tempIdBuiltIn = new Guid(item[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowInstanceID].ToString());
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You instead tried the SPListItem.Workflows property to get information about workflow instances running for a particular item?

Comment: It would be great to use just that approach.
I want to have Ids because I query tasklists with CAML and there are same tasks which belong to same wokflow..

My approach is to filter unique intance IDs from SPListITemCollection that I get in CAML query.

It raises a question: Can workflow instance IDs query with CAML clause ? 
That would be awesome?!

Comment: On second thought... it still would give me same results.